# Filtering JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

How to query in JArray?

I have JArray as follow:

```
"data": [
  {
   "type": "A",
    "serverTime": "2020-08-14T12:49:18.893+07:00"
  },
  {
    
    "type": "A",
    "serverTime": "2020-08-14T12:50:08.021+07:00"
  },
  {
    "serverTime": "2020-08-14T12:50:08.021+07:00",
    "type": "C",
  }
```

I expect to get a new JArray that already filtered by type = A

please help

Comment: Please show us your code so we can advise the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string jsonString = "{'data':[{'type':'A','serverTime':'2020-08-14T12:49:18.893+07:00'},{'type':'A','serverTime':'2020-08-14T12:50:08.021+07:00'},{'type':'C','serverTime':'2020-08-14T12:50:08.021+07:00'}]}";
            ////Note: You must convert to JObject

            var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

            var getArray = jsonObject["data"].Where(p => p["type"].ToString() == "A");
```

OR

```
JArray exampleArray = JArray.Parse(@"[
       {""type"": ""A"", ""serverTime"": ""2020-08-14T12:49:18.893+07:00""}, 
       {""type"": ""A"", ""serverTime"": ""2020-08-14T12:50:08.021+07:00""},
       {""type"": ""C"", ""serverTime"": ""2020-08-14T12:50:08.021+07:00""}
    ]");
            
            var result = exampleArray.Where(x => x["type"]?.ToString() == "A");
```

Your json format is wrong,

The right one

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "serverTime": "2020-08-14T12:49:18.893+07:00"
    },
    {
      "type": "A",
      "serverTime": "2020-08-14T12:50:08.021+07:00"
    },
    {
      "type": "C",
      "serverTime": "2020-08-14T12:50:08.021+07:00"
    }
  ]
}
```